# Inception style convolution

Tags: deep-learning, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I have the necessity to keep the model as small as possible to deploy an image classifier that can run efficiently on an app (the accuracy is not really relevant for me)

I recently approached deep learning and I haven't great experience, hence I'm currently playing with the cifar-10 example.
I tried to replace the first two 5x5 convolutional layers with two 3x3 convolution each, as described in the [inception paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1512.00567).

Unluckily, when I'm going to classify the test set, I got around 0.1 correct classification (random choice)

This is the modified code of the first layer (the second is similar):

```
with tf.variable_scope('conv1') as scope:
    kernel_l1 = _variable_with_weight_decay('weights_l1', shape=[3, 3, 3, 64],
                                     stddev=1e-4, wd=0.0)
    kernel_l2 = _variable_with_weight_decay('weights_l2', shape=[3, 3, 64, 1],
                                     stddev=1e-4, wd=0.0)
    biases = _variable_on_cpu('biases', [64], tf.constant_initializer(0.0))

    conv_l1 = tf.nn.conv2d(images, kernel_l1, [1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')
    conv_l2 = tf.nn.depthwise_conv2d(conv_l1, kernel_l2, [1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')
    bias = tf.nn.bias_add(conv_l2, biases)
    conv1 = tf.nn.relu(bias, name=scope.name)
    _activation_summary(conv1)
```

Is it correct?

Comment: The code does look correct, and changing the filter size to 3x3 should not change the test error rate so drastically. What error rate do you get on the training set?

Comment: I have not a good device for training yet (I only have a virtual machine on a simple laptop). Hence I stopped training after 7000 step. The original cifar10 code already guaranteed a 74% of correct classification, but not the modified version. Effectively during training I have a loss of 2.34, while the original cifar10 code has a loss lower than 1. I'm training to train longer the network and I'll let you know the results.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you're attempting to compute 64 features (for each 3x3 patch) in the first convolutional layer and feed this directly into the second convolutional layer, with no intermediate pooling layer. Convolutional neural networks typically have a structure of stacked convolutional layers, followed by contrast normalization and max pooling.

To reduce processing overheads researchers have experimented in moving from fully connected to [sparsely connected architectures](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1409.4842v1.pdf), and hence the creation of inception architecture. However, whilst these yield good results for high dimensional inputs, you may be expecting too much from the 32x32 pixels of Cifar10 in TensorFlow.

Therefore, I think the issue is less around patch size of and more to do with overall architecture. This [code](https://tensorflow.googlesource.com/tensorflow/+/master/tensorflow/models/image/cifar10/cifar10.py) is a known good starting point. Get this working and start reducing parameters until it breaks.

Comment: I'm trying to reproduce the scheme in the Google's inception paper. Given a well defined network, the goal is to reduce the parameter number, by replacing any convolution n x n (with n>3) through a sequence of smaller convolution (usually 3x3 or 1xn followed by nx1). In the example (see figure 1 of the paper cited in my question) they replace a 5x5 convolution with two 3x3 convolution executed one after the other, so that only 18 parameters are used instead of 25. This is repeated in each convolutional layer. Going "deeper", inception blocks use up to 5 convolutions sequentially (Figure 6).